# Laravel Multiple Auth using JWT auth every-time i get wrong password

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, jwt

I have 2 user i.e user and bus and for them i have different model
I am using laravel 5.5 with tymondesigns/jwt-auth 1.0.0-rc.1 verson

user is working perfect for user i am getting token also
 but bus user us getting 'invalid_email_or_password'

link to full code [full source code link](https://bitbucket.org/kobidkun/taxibackend)

**here is my user model:**

```
    class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject{
use Notifiable;
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
public function getJWTIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}
public function getJWTCustomClaims()
{
    return [];
}}
```

**my config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'bus' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'buses',
    ],
    'bus-api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'buses',
    ],
],
```

**my provider are :**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],

    //next
    'buses' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Bus::class,
    ],
```

my 
**my buslogincontroller which is taking user name & password for user table**

```
    public function busLogin(Request $request)
{
    \Config::set('jwt.user', "App\Bus");
    \Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Bus::class);
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    try {
        \Config::set('jwt.user', "App\Bus");
        \Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Bus::class);
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            \Config::set('jwt.user', "App\Bus");
            \Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Bus::class);
            return response()->json([
                'response' => 'error',
                'message' => 'invalid_email_or_password',
            ]);
        }
    } catch (JWTAuthException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'response' => 'error',
            'message' => 'failed_to_create_token',
        ]);
    }
    return response()->json([
        'response' => 'success',
        'result' => [
            'token' => $token,
            'message' => 'I am Admin user',
            'user' => '99',
        ],
    ]);
}
```

my routes api:

```
Route::post('bus/auth/login', 'Bus\Auth@busLogin');
Route::post('bus/auth/register', 'Bus\Auth@busRegister');
```

whenever I try to login with Bus model username & password i get invalid login in buscontroller login route but if i try to login with user model credintials i get token in return
how to setup multiple auth with jwtauth with laravel 5.5

Comment: Where are you setting the authentication guards for users and buses? Kernel? RouteServiceProvider? I would be helpful to see that.

Comment: i am setting up here config/auth.php full source code here
[link](https://bitbucket.org/kobidkun/taxibackend) .  thanks

Comment: It's much more useful to have the code posted within your question. I'd rather not dig through your repository when a simple edit would go further.

Comment: @btl . i config/auth.php is already given above thanks in advance

Comment: You misunderstand, where are you setting which guard a route will use? `Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api',...], function () { ...routes...});` for example.

Comment: As per guide which i was following it never said to add some guard i never added it

Comment: I tried added construct above all my function it didnot either

Comment: http://laravelcode.com/post/how-to-set-multi-authentication-in-jwt

Comment: You need to somehow tell the application which authentication mechanism to use for a given route. You probably have `auth` middleware assigned where the user login is concerned, but nothing saying "Use JWT for route X" where buses are to be authenticated.

Comment: And also i added $guard At model it also didn't work either

Comment: http://laravelcode.com/post/restful-api-in-laravel-55-using-jwt-authentication. Look at steps 5,6 and 7.

Comment: Ok let me try then i will get back to you it would be nice if you could share me the code anyways Thank you very much

Comment: I tried with the exact same code in a it did not work i was getting invalid credentials

Comment: I don't have any code to share for your implementation, I'm just going off past experience writing APIs. That link should help clarify what is missing for you though.

Comment: Let me try removing every thing and with a fresh start then

Comment: @btl I tried with exact code still same problem as i was getting above

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to change the providers in `config/auth.php`.

You can change the __construct function in each of your controllers as follows. So that jwt know which model to authenticate.

**BusController**

```
function __construct()
{
    Config::set('jwt.user', Bus::class);
    Config::set('auth.providers', ['users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Bus::class,
        ]]);
}
```

**AdminController**

```
function __construct()
{
    Config::set('jwt.user', Admin::class);
    Config::set('auth.providers', ['users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Admin::class,
        ]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set below code before route call in route api

```
\Config::set('jwt.user', "App\Bus");
\Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Bus::class);
```